# Has anyone successfully upgraded their headless Ubuntu running on a Dell PowerEdge T710 using a Keyboard, Video, Mouse console?

Tags: server, upgrade, dell, headless

Just as the title says.

I have headless Ubuntu server running on a Dell PowerEdge T710, and it says I need to do a release upgrade to 20.04.2 LTS from 18.04.5 LTS which I can perform using the Dell's inbuilt KVM (Keyboard, Video Mouse) console, via iDRAC (integrated Dell Remote Access Controller) but as I haven't done upgrades that way before, and before I actually perform the upgrade and end up with a broken system, I wanted to know if anyone has successfully done a clean, no problem, upgrade this way?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to upgrade. Any LTS has 5 years of support. 18.04 has support until April 2023.

Comment: I've done this with some T640 servers without any issue. One thing to be aware of is that you may have some issues with MySQL if it is installed on the system. 20.04 ships with MySQL 8.0, which usually upgrades the 5.x-series databases well, but there are hiccups from time to time. If you're upgrading a DB server, be ready in the event you need to remove MySQL, reinstall, and restore.

Comment: If I were to backup the MySQL databases using mysqldump, can I use the \. to import the sql backup file(s) after MySQl has been updated to 8.0 if the migration does not work?

Comment: I know LTS has a 5 year support, but this is for future information.